# How can GParted be used to fix "partition does not start on physical sector boundary problem"?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, 64-bit, hard-drive

**UPDATED**

I tried to learn GParted and use it with all the risks -_- and I think that I found a solution, but I still have problem, please read my question below

**this is from terminal after I move the sda7**

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00075eb1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   212723711   106258432    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       212725758  1953523711   870398977    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       212725760   410556415    98915328   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1937899520  1953523711     7812096   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       410560512   508213247    48826368   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       508216338  1937888819   714836241    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 8 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

**This output is from the terminal before I used GParted**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00075eb1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   212723711   106258432    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       212725758  1953523711   870398977    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       212725760   410556415    98915328   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1937899520  1953523711     7812096   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       410557203   508216274    48829536   83  Linux
Partition 7 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda8       508216338  1937888819   714836241    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Partition 8 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

It seems `/dev/sda7` fixed(I only tried with 1 partition first since its trial and error lol)
but there's problem with GParted as follows:

[Screen shoot from gparted](http://picturepush.com/public/12316952)

Is this normal?

One more question, I know this sounds stupid, but when I tried to resize `/dev/sda3`, I cant click the label "resize/move".

Comment: erm hi , i already read that question but unfortunately because of my stupidness i dont know how to use gparted correctly to fix this..

Comment: i dont really know if it does affect my laptop's performance, but everytime i copy/cut some file(s) the speed eventually decrease, like the 1-20 seconds it will be like 45MBps then it slows down to 15-18MBps and never go up but keep decreasing untill 15MBps

Comment: ok done i hope my question is accurate enough